# Why script hangs the host process when buffer size increases to 4MB?

Tags: c#, jscript, wsh

We have added Process class to execute a script. Main method of the script file is defined in the next section. When Script executed the WaitForExit() method of Process class returns false every time .

Code Snippet:

```
public void ExecuteTheScript()
{
.......
  
try  
  {
        System.Diagnostics.Process pProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        pProc.StartInfo.FileName = scriptPath;
        pProc.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptArguments;
        pProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(scriptPath);        
        pProc.Start();
        DateTime startTime = pProc.StartTime;
    
        bool bHasExited = pProc.WaitForExit(120 * 1000);               
    
        int timeElapsed = (int)(DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
        if (timeElapsed >= timeoutInSeconds && !bHasExited)
         {
             if (sError == null)
                 sError = "timeout and not Exited Properly"
             if (!pProc.HasExited)
                 pProc.Kill();
             bOk = false;
         }
         _stdOut = pProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
         _stdErr = pProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
          if (pProcess.ExitCode != 0)
           {
               if (sError == null)
                  sError = pProc.ExitCode.ToString();
               bOk = false;
            }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {   
       if (sError == null)
         sError = e.message;
       bOk = false;
    }
}
```

We are using Cscript to execute the script file.

```
function main
{
    var i;
    var exit_Code = 0;
    var str = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 51; i++) {
        WScript.Echo(str);
    }
    WScript.Quit(0);
}
```

Comment: Seems you're not using the Process class correctly.  We can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-6.0):

> The code example avoids a deadlock condition by calling
> `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` before `p.WaitForExit`. A deadlock condition
> can result if the parent process calls `p.WaitForExit` before
> `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` and the child process writes enough text to
> fill the redirected stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely
> for the child process to exit. The child process would wait
> indefinitely for the parent to read from the full StandardOutput
> stream.